# jQuery events: disable namespaces (or use an event with a period in the name)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use `.one()` to bind to an event with the name similar to `something.else.thing`, I am not able to change the event name since it comes from an external library.

The problem is because of the periods, jQuery creates namespaces, `else` and `thing` for the event `something` instead of creating an event named `something.else.thing`.

Is there any way around this?

Thanks

Edit:

Some example code:

```
$(document).on('appfeel.cordova.admob.onAdLoaded', function() {
    console.log('Does nothing');
});

document.addEventListener('appfeel.cordova.admob.onAdLoaded', function() {
    console.log('Works');
});
```

Comment: Have you tried escaping the periods? Not sure if that would work, but it's worth a try.

Comment: @JoshCrozier I've tried escaping with \ (`something\.else\.thing`) but it made no difference.

Comment: What library has an event named like that?

Comment: Could you provide a code?

Comment: @AtheistP3ace it's a cordova plugin, https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova

Comment: @pratikwebdev add an example in an edit to my question.

Comment: @marcusds made some additional comments to my answer. Could you look and let me know if that helps?

Comment: @marcusds As Atheist suggested try using Event name mentioned/registered within API in $(document).on(EVENT_NAME, handler); tweak and play a little. If it doesn't work anyhow you could use JS addEventListener for the same and in place of function() you can define your own handler and within that you can use the .one() Jquery on to element you want.

Comment: @pratikwebdev OP already said that `admob.events.onAdLoaded == "appfeel.cordova.admob.onAdLoaded"`

Comment: @JoshCrozier There is no way to escape a period for an event name in jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I decided to go about solving this issue. I went about it this way because this way allows me to continue to use jQuery and all the functionality it provides while keeping my code consistent and only requires a few lines of extra code to go about.

```
$(document).one('somethingElseThing', function() {
    console.log('Event!');
});
document.addEventListener('something.else.thing', function() {
    $(document).trigger('somethingElseThing');
});
```

What I am doing is using straight JavaScript to create an event listener for the event with a period in the name and then I have it trigger a custom event that doesn't a have a period so that I can continue to use jQuery. This I believe is an easy straightforward approach.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can disable jQuery event namespacing so if you want to use `one` on an event with dots in it you can just do this in pure JS:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/8z6ewwnv/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="test"></div>
<button id="mybutton">Run event again</button>
```

JS:

```
var test = document.getElementById('test');
var button = document.getElementById('mybutton');
var event = new Event('something.else.blah');

function onWeirdEvent () {
    test.removeEventListener('something.else.blah', onWeirdEvent);
    alert('did it');
}

test.addEventListener('something.else.blah', onWeirdEvent, false);

test.dispatchEvent(event);

button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    test.dispatchEvent(event);
}, false);
```

Its essentially the same thing. If you really want everything to seem jQuery-ish create a custom plugin:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/8z6ewwnv/2/

```
$.fn.customOne = function (eventString, fn) {
    var self = this[0];
    var origFn = fn;
    fn = function (event) {
        self.removeEventListener(eventString, fn);
        return origFn.apply(self);
    };
    self.addEventListener(eventString, fn, false);
};

$.fn.customTrigger = function (eventString) {
    var event = new Event(eventString);
    var self = this[0];
    self.dispatchEvent(event);
}

$('#test').customOne('something.else.blah', function () {
    alert('did it');
});
$('#test').customTrigger('something.else.blah');
$('#test').customTrigger('something.else.blah');
```

Comment: admob.events.onAdLoaded = "appfeel.cordova.admob.onAdLoaded", so it makes no difference.

I want to use jQuery so I can use function such as one().

Comment: @marcusds OK, wasn't sure what value it held. Updated my question for some pure JS one support. You can continue using jquery but implement your own one.

Comment: @marcusds if one, is all you need, you can easily create an `addOnceEventListener`

Comment: @marcusds Updated answer to show you how to build a custom jquery one plugin that does what you want.

Comment: Don't make the `customOne` a jQuery plugin, it doesn't use any jQuery functionality, no need for the coupling, don't give in:)

Comment: While I agree with you @JuanMendes, and I would not personally do it myself some people when using a library like jQuery prefer to stick with code that does things in the same looking way as the library they use. My work was like that. I could do things with better performance outside of jQuery but they would complain I wasn't using jQuery to do these things even though its just essentially a javascript wrapper. I eventually convinced them to remove jQuery and go to pure JS but some people are just like that.